# Android - how to keep an AutoCompleteTextView from keeping focus

Tags: android, textview

I have a pretty complex layout that has multiple types of views and I have one AutoCompleteTextView that keeps focus. I have relativeLayouts which I keep set to GONE and then when I expand them the screen shoots back up to the autoCompleteTextView which is annoying when you are way down the view. How can I keep the AutocompleteTextView from keeping focus without setting it to not being able to take focus because when you do this you cant click on it to write in it. I tried setting it to not take focus and adding an onclick listener where I basically said if not in focus take focus but that didnt work. I would like to be able to have it so I can start the activity with the AutoCompleteTextView having no focus and then when someone clicks on it they can write in it and when they are done it loses focus. Any help on the matter would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place this on its `parents layout (like linearLayout)`:

`android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`

This way `LinearLayout` will take focus when user join your activity and the keyboard will not show.

Comment: that works for the start of the activity but how can I make the focus of the autocompleteTextView go away after the user is done typing input into it.

Comment: You can requestFocus() from another componnent, but the hard part is, how will you know when the user is done typing?

Comment: I suppose I could just call requestFocus() in any onclick that I have for any other object in the main view. Ill give it a shot and see what happens

Comment: Well, typically it should lose the focus automatically when you click in a button, cause button will gain focus "just after" click... If it is not the behaviour, maybe I misunderstood the question.